# How to retrieve AB-test data/tweaks from Mixpanel?

Tags: mixpanel

Is it possible to retrieve data about A-B Tests using the Mixpanel API. For example fetching all AB-Tests including their tweaks? It seems like the [java API](https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/java) only provides Events, People and aggregated data, but not the "master data" we configured in Mixpanel.

Answer (score 0):

How did you set up the A/B testing data in Mixpanel? Usually these data is setup as property to an event e.g. "Variation Name: A" will be the super property that is attached to all relevant events.

You would then be able to pull any event and find that specific property through the API.